# Problem related to mp inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Show that

$X′V^{-1}X(X′V^{−1}X)^{+}X′ = X′$

for any positive definite matrix V.

My attempt:

I am writing $V^{-1} = GG'$, and then substituting it in the LHS of the above equation.

LHS = $X'GG'X(X'GG'X)^{+}X'$

Assuming $X'G = B$, I get

LHS = $BB'(BB')^{+}X'$ = $BB'B'^{+}B^{+}X'$

I am stuck here and don't know how to reduce it from here to RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X'=BG^{-1}$. Hence you need to show that
$$BB'(BB')^+B=B$$
Let $B=P\Sigma Q'$ be the singular value decomposition where
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$,
$\Sigma_1$ is $r\times r$ diagonal matrix where $r=\operatorname{rank}B$. So,
$$BB'=P\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_1^2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} P' ~~\text{and}~~ (BB')^+=P\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_1^{-2}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} P'$$
Therefore,
$$BB'(BB')^+B=P\begin{bmatrix}I_r&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}Q'=B$$